# Are charge and energy inter-convertible?

Tags: electrostatics

During pair annihilation ([(e-)+(e+)]-------->gamma radiation}is it not that charges in pair (yet opposite)are converted into energy, and does this also mean that energy(gamma radiation) can be converted into charge..and vice versa(during the reverse process-pair production)?
In general, does a law of charge-energy equivalence exist?

P.S:detailed answer is requested, as i am a beginner..sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they're not, because they both must be conserved. A single electron cannot just transform into photons, because the electron has negative charge and the photons have zero charge.

What's going on the pair annihilation process (the most common case being $e^+ e^- \to \gamma\gamma$) is that different forms of energy are being converted into each other: the electron and positron have energy due to their movement and also due to their mass; the photons have no mass, so their energy is entirely kinetic, but the total is the same before and after.

Now, this doesn't rule out the opposite process $\gamma\gamma \to e^+ e^-$, and as far as I know it's entirely possible for two gamma photons to transform into an electron-positron pair. But the net charge is always zero.